# Building a menu from a div with A span then writing it to a different "navbar" div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="source">
     <a href="some link">link 1</a>
     <a href="some link">link 2</a>
     <a.... and so on
<div>
```

i know how to get the link and  span content using

```
  $("#source a").each(function () {

   })
```

and the length using

```
    var ctr = $("#source a").length;
```

now I am confuse how to write it on a 'navbar' div on bootstrap, so i can generate a dropdown menu from it.

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            Generate it here....
           </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I know it's pretty easy for you javascript masters and jquery gods.So thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add them all like this (if I understand correctly):

```
$("#source").children().each(function () {
    $("#navbar .dropdown-menu")
        .append($("<li></li>")
        .append(this));
});
```

Comment: yeah..i was about to post that i got it.Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: $("#navbuttons a").each(function () {

          $("#dropmenu").append("<li><a>woot" + ctr++ + "</a></li>");
         ........

Comment: i wanted to vote..lol..i only got 1 rep..i've always search in here..but this is the 1st time i joined in..